# The entity type States is not part of the model for the current context in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm getting an error in my generic repository.

I am using a generic repository with Entity Framework and a database-first approach.

This is my `context.cs`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}

 public virtual DbSet<tblUser> tblUsers { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<tblState> tblStates { get; set; }`
```

**HomeRepository**: when I am using this code as non generic, I am getting the records

```
public IEnumerable<States> GetAllwithoutGeneric()
{
    return _dbContext.Set<tblState>() .
    Select(x => new States {  name = x.name}).ToList();
}

var state1 = homeRepository.GetAllwithoutGeneric();
```

And I'm getting result in `state1` variable of the controller. The above code is working fine.

Once I am using a generic repository

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllState()
{
  return _dbContext.Set<T>();
}
```

and calling above code like this:

```
HomeRepository<States> homeRepository = new HomeRepository<States>();
var state = homeRepository.GetAllState().ToList();
```

I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type States is not part of the model for the current context

Once I am using to call same tblState entity using non generic I am getting the result, and when I am passing the State.cs to generic method getting above error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DbSet` type is `tblState`, not `States`. So you have to use `tblState` instead of `States` as follows:

```
HomeRepository<tblState> homeRepository = new HomeRepository<tblState>();
var state = homeRepository.GetAllState().ToList();
```

Now if you want to convert the output to `States` then do as follows:

```
var state = homeRepository.GetAllState()
                          .Select(x => new States {  name = x.name}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But I want to use my model not entity generated model, I have created a folder to keep all the model so that it can be share everywhere I want. After changing the name from States to tblState not working yet.

Comment: @Sheriff See my updated answer please! Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes, you are right and it working too. But I want to user                                  
`public IQueryable<T> GetAllState()
{
  return _dbContext.Set<T>();
}`                                                                                                                     Here when I am passing States but in case of generic respository above error I am getting. Once I will pass tblState of EF genereated model in place of T then it work fine, but in case of States passing from controller in generic method getting error.

Comment: Yes! You have to use it as exactly as I have shown..Moreover now you can click the check sign left to the answer to mark it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have resolved itself by creating an other library project and keeping all the entity with the same name as it was created by EF in library project.

Now we can give the reference of this library project in both Repository and Entity framework.

Now both project have the same entity so there won't be any error.

Thanks,
Sheriff